# Taking Samples From a Mixture Model

Tags: r, probability, distributions, normal-distribution, stochastic-processes

I am interested in knowing if Monte Carlo algorithms can be used to take samples from a Gaussian Mixture Model. Suppose I have the following Gaussian Mixture Model (2 Components, 4 Dimensional - I assume that the variance-covariance matrix for both components is the same, but the means are different). I represent this using the R programming language ("target"):

```
#actual multivariate function is defined below ("target")
    target <- function(x,y,z,w)

    {
      x_one = x - 5.0060022
      x_two = y - 3.4280049
      x_three = z - 1.4620007
      x_four = w - 0.2459998

      x_t = c(x_one, x_two, x_three, x_four)
      x_t_one <- matrix(x_t, nrow=4, ncol= 1, byrow = TRUE)
      x_t_two =  matrix(x_t, nrow=1, ncol= 4, byrow = TRUE)


      # In this part, as it's (x-mu)^T * SIGMA * (x-mu)

      #num = exp(-0.5 * t(x_t_t) %*% sigma1_inv %*% x_t_t)
      num = exp(-0.5 * x_t_two  %*%  sigma_inv  %*%  x_t_one)

      answer_1 = num/denom
      return(answer_1)
    


#define constants needed for the multivariate normal
    sigma1 <- c(0.15065114 , 0.13080115 ,  0.02084463 , 0.01309107 , 0.13080115 , 0.17604529 ,  0.01603245 , 0.01221458 , 0.02084463 , 0.01603245  , 0.02808260 , 0.00601568 , 0.01309107 , 0.01221458 ,  0.00601568 , 0.01042365)
      sigma2 <- matrix(sigma1, nrow=4, ncol= 4, byrow = TRUE)
      sigma_inv2 <- solve(sigma2)
      sigma_det2 <- det(sigma2)
      denom2 = sqrt( (2*pi)^4 * sigma_det2) 


      x_one2 = x - 8
      x_two2 = y - 1
      x_three2 = z - 2
      x_four2 = w - 3.1

      x_t2 = c(x_one2, x_two2, x_three2, x_four2)
      x_t_one2 <- matrix(x_t2, nrow=4, ncol= 1, byrow = TRUE)
      x_t_two2 =  matrix(x_t2, nrow=1, ncol= 4, byrow = TRUE)


      # In this part, as it's (x-mu)^T * SIGMA * (x-mu)

      #num = exp(-0.5 * t(x_t_t) %*% sigma1_inv %*% x_t_t)
      num2 = exp(-0.5 * x_t_two2  %*%  sigma_inv2  %*%  x_t_one2)

      answer_2 = num2/denom2
      return(0.3*answer_1 + 0.7*answer_2)
    }
```

For this Gaussian Mixture Model, suppose I want to find out the most likely value of "x" when "y = z = w = 1".

**1)**I attempted to write the code for the  Metropolis-Hastings Algorithm for randomly sampling the conditional probability distribution of this Gaussian Mixture Model P(x | y = z = w =1)

```
#conditional distribution
    target1 <- function(x,y,z,w)

    {
      x_one = x - 5.0060022
      x_two =  1- 3.4280049
      x_three = 1 - 1.4620007
      x_four = 1 - 0.2459998

      x_t = c(x_one, x_two, x_three, x_four)
      x_t_one <- matrix(x_t, nrow=4, ncol= 1, byrow = TRUE)
      x_t_two =  matrix(x_t, nrow=1, ncol= 4, byrow = TRUE)


      # In this part, as it's (x-mu)^T * SIGMA * (x-mu)

      #num = exp(-0.5 * t(x_t_t) %*% sigma1_inv %*% x_t_t)
      num = exp(-0.5 * x_t_two  %*%  sigma_inv  %*%  x_t_one)

      answer_1 = num/denom
      
    


#define constants needed for the multivariate normal
    sigma1 <- c(0.15065114 , 0.13080115 ,  0.02084463 , 0.01309107 , 0.13080115 , 0.17604529 ,  0.01603245 , 0.01221458 , 0.02084463 , 0.01603245  , 0.02808260 , 0.00601568 , 0.01309107 , 0.01221458 ,  0.00601568 , 0.01042365)
      sigma2 <- matrix(sigma1, nrow=4, ncol= 4, byrow = TRUE)
      sigma_inv2 <- solve(sigma2)
      sigma_det2 <- det(sigma2)
      denom2 = sqrt( (2*pi)^4 * sigma_det2) 


      x_one2 = x - 8
      x_two2 = 1 - 1
      x_three2 = 1 - 2
      x_four2 = 1 - 3.1

      x_t2 = c(x_one2, x_two2, x_three2, x_four2)
      x_t_one2 <- matrix(x_t2, nrow=4, ncol= 1, byrow = TRUE)
      x_t_two2 =  matrix(x_t2, nrow=1, ncol= 4, byrow = TRUE)


      # In this part, as it's (x-mu)^T * SIGMA * (x-mu)

      #num = exp(-0.5 * t(x_t_t) %*% sigma1_inv %*% x_t_t)
      num2 = exp(-0.5 * x_t_two2  %*%  sigma_inv2  %*%  x_t_one2)

      answer_2 = num2/denom2
      return(0.3*answer_1 + 0.7*answer_2)
    }
```

**2)** Then, I used the Metropolis Hastings Algorithm to evaluate samples from the conditional distribution:

```
library(mvtnorm)
x = rep(0,10000)


x[1] = 3     #initialize; I've set arbitrarily set this to 3 and 1


for(i in 2:10000){
  current_x = x[i-1]
  
 
  new = rmvnorm(n=1, mean=c(current_x), sigma=diag(1), method="chol")   # generate bivariate random numbers
  proposed_x = new[1]
 

  A = target1(proposed_x)/target1(current_x) 
  if(runif(1)<A){
    x[i] = proposed_x       # accept move with probabily min(1,A)
          
   
    } else {
    x[i] = current_x        # otherwise "reject" move, and stay where we are
   
 
    }
}
```

**3)** According to results of the Metropolis-Hastings Algorithm, the expected value of at y=z=w=1 should be:

```
plot(density(x))
```

[image]

```
mean(x)

3.39
```

**Question:** Can someone please tell me if I am right? Can Monte Carlo Algorithms be used to evaluate random samples from Gaussian Mixture Models? Is what I have done correct?

Thanks